# How to Retrieve data from a Google Spreadsheet File to another and put hyperlinks?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, spreadsheet, importrange

I have 2 workbooks on Google Drive, WB(A) - 10 different sheets and WB(B) - only one sheet.

I want to retrieve some data from certain cells from WB(B) from every sheet to store and update at WB(A), i.e., Name from cell (C6), ID from cell (J10), Eva from cell (M13), and same cells as well from all sheets 1,2,3,4,....,10.

I managed to handle the data retrieval process and update between WB(B) and WB(A) using a script and time-variant triggers. I need to assign a hyperlink in WB(A) that's visible on the ID cell for each and every row (per record), **or** create a separate column containing hyperlinks related to every record on its own. the purpose is to click on ID with the hyperlink that it will transfer you automatically to the corresponding sheet that has these values

I know how to do it manually, but I want it to be generated automatically and dynamically via a script, i will handle the trigger.

this is my code

```
function VerandacopyData() {

  var Veranda_Workbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById("WB(B) id");

//var workbookB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var Veranda_Sheets = Veranda_Workbook.getSheets();

//Destination link id and sheet name

  var sheetA = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Log & Record ID').getSheetByName('Veranda Record');
  sheetA.clear(); 

// This deletes all data in WB(A) before copying everything from WB(B), use this only if you don't want //all data to be duplicated all the time.

for(var index = 0; index < Veranda_Sheets.length; index++) {

//Sources definitions and reading data from all sheets

    var lastRow = sheetA.getLastRow() + 1;
    var Name_Source    = Veranda_Sheets[index].getRange(6,3,1,1).getValues();
    var ID_Source   = Veranda_Sheets[index].getRange(9,10,1,1).getValues();
    var Eva_Date_Source    = Veranda_Sheets[index].getRange(6,13,1,1).getValues();

//Destination definition according to copied ranges criteria
//In big overall record sheet, we try lastRow+1 to not delete the header if it was buggy and/or delete //Line 13 ==> sheetA.clear();

  var Name_Destination  = sheetA.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 1);
    var ID_Destination  = sheetA.getRange(lastRow, 3, 1, 1)
    var Eva_Destination   = sheetA.getRange(lastRow, 4, 1, 1)

//Setting Values in destination in Evaluations Record sheet  

    Name_Destination.setValues(Name_Source);
    ID_Scope_Destination.setValues(ID_Source);
    Eva_Destination.setValues(Eva_Source);
     }}
```

I found the solution, by writing these lines when the For loop begins:

```
var Sheets_Name = new Array()
var Sheets_ID   = new Array()

Sheets_Name.push( [ Veranda_Sheets[index].getName() ] )
Sheets_ID.push( [ Veranda_Sheets[index].getSheetId() ] )
    sheetA.getRange(lastRow,1).setFormula('=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ABCDEFEGGJKLSDKSDLSKDLKSDLKNXZDSKBD/edit#gid=' + Sheets_ID +'")');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function VerandacopyData() {
  var ssb=SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
  var bshts=ssb.getSheets();
  var vrsht=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Log & Record ID').getSheetByName('Veranda Record');
  vrsht.clear(); 
  for(var i=0;i<bshts.length;i++) {
    var lastRow=vrsht.getLastRow()+1;
    var Name_Source=bshts[i].getRange(6,3,1,1).getValue();
    var ID_Source=bshts[i].getRange(9,10,1,1).getValue();
    var Eva_Source=bshts[i].getRange(6,13,1,1).getValue();
    vrsht.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 1).setValue(Name_Source);
    vrsht.getRange(lastRow, 3, 1, 1).setValue(ID_Source);
    vrsht.getRange(lastRow, 4, 1, 1).setValue(Eva_Source);
  }
}
```

Comment: but where're the hyperlinks on ID_Source cells after you retrieve the data?
thank you though for your effort and taking time to answer my question))

Comment: PS. my code works fine for retrieving the data with and without triggers.. I just need to put a hyperlink on the ID_Source cell for each sheet it already came from.. so when you hover on ID_Source cells and click the link, it opens its corresponding sheet.

Answer (score 0):

To change your ID cells to be shown as a hyperlink, you can use the setFormula() [1] function instead of the setValues funciton, only change the following line:

```
ID_Scope_Destination.setValues(ID_Source);
```

For this:

```
var Sheet_ID = Veranda_Sheets[index].getSheetId()
ID_Scope_Destination.setFormula('=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEET-ID]/edit#gid=' + Sheet_ID + '","' + ID_Source[0] + '")');
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String)